# Different types of nodes in graph theory

Tags: graph, networkx, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I am trying to figure out whether a path in a graph has various branches or not. For example, this path does not:

[image]

But this branch does:

[image]

Degree of the orange node > 2. Is there a term to denote whether a graph or node is 'branchable' or not? It seems like this is sometimes called a "junction": https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-a-node-and-junction-in-electrical-circuits

Comment: *I am trying to figure out whether a path in a graph has various branches or not*. A path is a sequence of branches from node A to node B. If *branching* leads to the path ending in another node, then it is not the same path.

Comment: @jrook in plain speak I mean if there are any potential forks in a path ("Two paths diverged...")

Comment: Using [definition from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path), is it correct to say you want to distinguish between *walks* which strictly are not *paths* and those which are.

Comment: In your question the two walks corresponding to the two graphs would be : {1,2,3,4} and {1,2,3,2,4}. The first one is a path, the second one is not.

Answer (score -1):

there is no such term yet you can determine whether a node is a root or a leaf. leaf nodes don't have successors such as the pink and red nodes in graph 2, they only have ancestors. in other words, they have incoming edges and no out coming edges (if we imply that it's a directed graph)